# On Lift "Class not found" when deploying on Tomcat

Tags: scala, tomcat, deployment, lift

I've been trying to run my Lift app on Google App Engine, then gave up and tried Cloudbees. Then on a local Tomcat instance and I found that they ALL have the same error: classes are missing at some level or another.

I tried a fresh installation of Lift. The one I just downloaded is 2.6-M2. I used the package command on it and put it into Tomcat. I get Class not found errors. The error I get, this time, is for:

- `FoBo.Bs3Navbar.builder`
- `FoBo.Bs3Navbar.builderPullRight`
- `FoBo.Bs3LinkedListGroup.builder`
- `helloWorld.howdy`

Clearly, something is missing in the way the WAR file is built.

I also tried going into the `target/webapp` folder and trying the command `jar cvf list_test.war .`, but I got the same result.

Everything works in sbt's built-in Jetty server. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Still working on it. But it seems the problem is not with Lift, Jetty, OR Tomcat. Doing the exact same thing on another computer works. I'm still very puzzled by the whole thing. Still investigating.

EDIT 2:

Okay. I know what's wrong. Lift is trying to write to the H2 database, which means creating files, and to write a log file. GAE won't allow that. Can I simply not use H2 with GAE? And how to I prevent Lift from ever writing any log files or make it log things in a way that works with GAE? Thanks.

Comment: When I get a Class not found error for my Lift application, it usually means there's something wrong with the way that the WAR file was built. Diagnosing the problem usually involves figuring out *why* the classes in question didn't make it into the WAR file.